# Promise.allSettled returns only last promise despite all promises fulfilled correctly

Tags: node.js, for-loop, axios, promise

I am trying to fulfill promises in batches of 20 by pushing them into an array, like this:

```
async function addTitle (host,title) {
  const options: {
    method:"put",
    url: host,
    data: title
  }
return await axios.request(options)
}

let titlesPromises = [];
titlesPromises .push(()=>{
  addTitle(host,title)
});

if (titlesPromises.length >= 20) {
  promises= titlesPromises.map((fn) => fn());
  responses = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
  for (const response of responses) {
    console.log(`Title ${JSON.parse(response.value.config.data).titleNam} was updated with status code ${response.value.status}.`);
  }
}
```

I can see that all promises were fulfilled correctly at the endpoint system, and all titles were added correctly.
However, the console.log only returns a single title:

```
Title Journal of All Titles was updated with status code 204.
Title Journal of All Titles was updated with status code 204.
Title Journal of All Titles was updated with status code 204.
Title Journal of All Titles was updated with status code 204.
Title Journal of All Titles was updated with status code 204.
Title Journal of All Titles was updated with status code 204.
...
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I tried changing the code to run with .then:

```
Promise.allSettled(promises).then((responses) => {
  for (const response of responses) {
  console.log(`Title ${JSON.parse(response.value.config.data).titleNam} was updated with status code ${response.value.status}.`);
  }
})
```

But the result is unsurprisingly the same.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Please post your actual code - `function.addTitle` is a syntax error, and `responses` will be an array of `undefined`s since your `titlePromses` functions (notice they are not actually promises!) do not `return` anything.

Comment: I cannot post the actual code because the url is private. As you can see in the code, it is a placeholder. In the actual code I import it from an external file.
Right now it will give an error because there is no value for host and title.

Comment: Yes, the url does not matter to us, but you need to post a [mcve] that is syntactically valid and produces the problematic behaviour.

Comment: `function.addTitle` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Sorry, that is a leftover from me calling the function from a separate file.
I fixed the code to just use the present function.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the promises: `titlesPromises.push(() => {return addTitle(host,title)})`. Or remove the `{}`

Comment: @slebetman Yes, but that's still likely not the solution, because if `titlesPromises.push(()=>{ addTitle(host,title) });` was the actual code they were using, they wouldn't be getting the output ("*Title Journal of All Titles was updated with status code 204.*") they claim to get.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I honestly have no idea why this worked, but apparently a setting up a limit worked to solve the issue:

```
import pLimit from 'p-limit';
const limit = pLimit(20);
await limit(() => Promise.allSettled(titlesPromises.map((fn) => fn())))
```

Not sure why putting the limit would make a difference since the code already caps the array at 20, but apparently it makes some change I am unaware of.

Comment: If that is a solution, it's an indication of a bug in your backend not handling concurrent requests properly

Comment: That is absolutely possible. It won't be the first bug I've found for our backend system.
I'll report it to the development team.
Thanks!